# how to get the focus of MyLinedit?

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt application development. In my Application i have built a QWERTY keypad usign QSignalMapper.I have 3 QLineEdit boxes above this keypad area. Now, when ever  i select any line,
i didnt get to know which line object gets selected.

If i subclass QLineEdit, and Reimplement this, than also i am not knowing which particular line has the
current focus.If i presses line edit box, and start typing into that with keypad, focus moves to keypad's button.

Than,how can i get to know which line edit has been selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `QLineEdit::focusInEvent` in order to remember which line edit was last focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your keypad buttons to never accept focus.  This way, the focus won't leave the line edit when keypad buttons are pressed.